# How to send argument securely using Process class?

Tags: c#, svn, command-line, windows-console

I'm using System.Diagnostics.Process to execute an svn command from a windows console application. This is the configuration of the process:

```
svn.StartInfo.FileName = svnPath;
svn.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("copy {0}/trunk/ {0}/tags/{1} -r head -q --username {3} --password {4} -m \"{2}\"", basePathToRepo, tagName, message, svnUserName, svnPassword);
svn.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
svn.Start();
svn.WaitForExit();
```

My problem is that those arguments, which include the svn credentials, are sent (I suppose) in an unsecure way.

Is there a way to send these arguments in a secure way using the Process class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using the standard command line mechanism, which is going to be the same as any other method.  There is no "secure" way to send a command line argument to a program, as it's just a standard process.

That being said, this **is** going to only be accessible locally, since you're running this in the local user's account already.  This is just as secure as having the user type this into a Command Prompt window...

Comment: You're right... thanks a lot to get me out of the confussion.

Answer (score 1):

send where? they are passed from your code to WinApi. it is in-memory operation, it is secure enough.

Comment: +1 for secure enough, it's far more likely the SVN credentials would be taken from inside your application directly as opposed to trying to intercept that shell execution.

Comment: write your own svn.exe that captures data.... and here all security ends. but it is not about Process class